# Signed or unsigned result of operation

Tags: verilog

Let's consider three cases:

```
// case 1
reg [63:0] result;
reg [15:0] number1;
reg signed [31:0] number2;

number1 = 0;
number2 = -2147483648;

result = number1 | number2;  // result[63] == 0
```

```
// case 2
reg [63:0] result;
reg [15:0] number1;

number1 = 0;

result = number1 | -32'd2147483648;  // result[63] == 1
```

```
// case 3
reg [63:0] result;
reg [15:0] number1;

number1 = 0;

result = number1 | $signed(-32'd2147483648);  // result[63] == 0
```

Why result of case two is signed? Why verilog treat this equation in different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case the size of the operands are defined by the size of the lhs -- 64 bits. System verilog standard provides rules of calculating bit widths and types of expressions based on the width and types of the operands and lhs. In all cases the width of the '|' is context dependent and must have 64 bits (max width of all operands and lsh). As a result, it expects that all operands are matched the max width.

case 1:

```
result = number1 | number2;
```

The resulting expression is simply an 'or' of both 16-bit operands 0-extended to 64. So, bit 63 is 0. Note, there is no negation

case 2:

```
result = number1 | -32'd2147483648;  
result = number1 | -2147483648; // same as above
result = number1 | -number2; // same result
```

The unary 'minus' is also a context-determined operator. What happens here, the '-' operator will extend its operand to 64 bits before negating it. As a result you will nave a 64-bit negative number with bit 63 set to 1.

case 3

```
result = number1 | $signed(-32'd2147483648);
```

Here, the width of the context is not propagated through the  $signed function to its operand, which is 32 bit wide and is self-determined. The type of the context is always unsigned due to the operator '|'. As a result, the rhs is treated as unsigned even though you marked it as signed. So, it is also gets zero-extended to 64 bits and bit 63 is 0.

The difference between 2 and 3 is that negation works on the 64 bit value (in 2), versus 32-bit value (in 3). In both cases this operand is treated as unsigned.

perand to $signed a self-determined width of 32. Its negation makes it a positive number in the 32-bit context. So, after the $signed operator, it is a 32-bit positive number, which get 0-extended to 64 bits.